# backing up certain files in a folder using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a couple of questions.  I have certain binaries in a folder...

```
F:\program files\application\Client\
```

I only want to copy the latest dll's that have a certain phrase in there names.  Lets say "MVCsite".  I know you can use `Get-ChildItem -Filter` with the filter parameters, to get just child items with a .dll extension, but is there a way to look for specific files with specific keywords, or am I going to have to literally copy a list of files out of the directory and move it to a back up folder?  Is there a quick and dirty command to do that?  As you can tell, I am new to powershell, but I am learning fast.

Comment: It there just a single keyword, or can there be more than one of them?

Comment: There can be more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gci -path $path -filter "*.dll" | where {$_.Name -match "Keyword1|Keyword2|etc"}`

Comment: `Get-ChildItem`, same as you posted :) it can also be used as `ls` or `dir`

Comment: "-contains" won't work. I've taken the liberty of editing your answer. I hope you don't mind. Also it seems that there can be more than one keyword, so I've put those in too.

Comment: Can you have multiple -filter params?  can you send an array to -filter?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it may only take a `[string]`, not an array

Answer (score 0):

Simply use wildcards in your **-Path** parameter:

```
Copy-Item F:\program files\application\Client\*MVCsite*.dll X:\DestinationDir
```

That will copy all files in **F:\program files\application\Client\** whose names contain the string "MVCsite" and have the extension ".dll". Is that what you wanted to accomplish? If not, please clarify.

Comment: I guess technically I could just put an array into that -Path parameter If I new all the files I wanted to copy.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. Yes, you could do it that way, but putting that array together would be rather tedious. I thought the idea was to copy all files that have a certain extension and a certain string in their names. Are you trying to say that you think this solution requires you to list all the filenames individually? It doesn't. That one line copies *all* files that have "MVCsite" in the name and the ".dll" extension, all at once.

Comment: I know what you mean, I guess I was kind of 'thinking out loud' kindof, I was wondering if there was some kind of trade off, when I could simply just list all the files I need.  But your answer is fine as well.